# Pandas: combine different CSVs in one df combining by the name

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have some different csv files in a same folder with this structure:

CSV 1:

```
    Name      Passes     Shots
1   Player 1     20        5
2   Player 2     30        6
3   Player 3     10        3
```

CSV 2:

```
    Name      Goals     Duels
1   Player 3     2        3
2   Player 1     0        2
3   Player 2     1        7
```

CSV 3:

```
    Name      Country     Age
1   Player 2     SPA        25
2   Player 3     SPA        26
3   Player 1     USA        23
```

I would like to combine this csvs in one dataframe with pandas and the result I want would be:

```
     Name    Passes     Shots    Goals    Duels    Country    Age
1   Player 1     20        5       0        2        USA       23
2   Player 2     30        6       1        7        SPA       25
3   Player 3     10        3       2        3        SPA       26
```

I'm trying to combine them with this code but i get a dataframe with 9 rows (Player 1 3 times, Player 2 3 times and Player 3 3 times):

```
file_extension = ".csv"

all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob(f"*{file_extension}")]

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in all_filenames])
```

The result I get is something like:

```
     Name    Passes     Shots    Goals    Duels    Country    Age
1   Player 1     20        5      NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN
2   Player 2     30        6      NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN
3   Player 3     10        3      NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN
1   Player 1    NaN      NaN       0        2        NaN      NaN
2   Player 2    NaN      NaN       1        7        NaN      NaN
3   Player 3    NaN      NaN       2        3        NaN      NaN
1   Player 1    NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN      USA       23
2   Player 2    NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN      SPA       25
3   Player 3    NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN      SPA       26
```

Any idea of how to combine them as I want, with the name as the reference? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and specify the left and right keys

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Player 3'],
    'Passes': [20, 30, 10],
    'Shots': [5, 6, 3]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Player 3', 'Player 1', 'Player 2'],
    'Goals': [2, 0, 1],
    'Duels': [3, 2, 7]
})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Player 2', 'Player 3', 'Player 1'],
    'Country': ['SPA', 'SPA', 'USA'],
    'Age': [25, 26, 23]
})

df1.merge(df2, left_on="Name", right_on="Name").merge(
    df3, left_on="Name", right_on="Name")
```

Output:

```
        Name    Passes  Shots   Goals   Duels   Country Age
0   Player 1        20     5    0          2    USA     23
1   Player 2        30     6    1          7    SPA     25
2   Player 3        10     3    2          3    SPA     26
```

#### Edit 1:

If you have many such file and all of them have `Name` as key then you can use:

```
df = None
for f in list_of_files:
  df = pd.read_csv(f) if df is None else df.merge(
      pd.read_csv(f), left_on="Name", right_on="Name")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have a lot of csvs (more than 50)... should I read one by one in different dfs and then merge? Isn't there a solution for read and combine at the same time?

Comment: I've tried but unfortunately it shows a blank dataframe, with all the columns but 0 rows

Comment: Make sure your "Name" columns are all proper

Comment: I've checked and all of them have Name column. The df is still blank, with all the columns but no rows

Answer (score 1):

A way around drop_duplicates is just by merging on multiple column headers. That way if there is a player that has played on two different teams the player_name will be the same but the team will be different and the merge will recognize that.

You can also use pandas to read in the CSV into a data frame (since you have a lot to read, this can be in a large for-loop).

```
data1 = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV = '/your_csv.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV = '/your_second_csv.csv')

merged_df = pd.merge(data1, data2, how='outer', on=['player', 'team']
```

Something else to note with data frame manipulation is that you can concatenate them together on an axis in order to bring them together. It can look something like this...

```
df_list = []
for loop {
   data = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV = '/your_csv.csv')
   # check type of data to make sure its a dataframe
   df_list.append(data)
   # and on to the next csv
}
# after the for loop you can concatenate the data frames together
concat_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, sort=False)
# need to make sure the first df_list is iterable or else you will get an error
# then you can create a new csv with all of your data
concat_df.to_csv(OUTPUT_PATH + '/your_new_csv.csv', index=False)
```